# Cannot get proper values for RSRP & RSRQ from CellSignalStrengthLte Android

Tags: android, lte

I am using CellSignalStrengthLte to get LTE parameters. But if we refer the documentation at [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthLte.html) , you will find that there is no direct method to get values for these.
However, if we do .toString() to the CellSignalStrengthLte object, we get parameters such as ss,rsrp,rsrq,rssnr,cqi,ta. But the rsrp and rsrq give wrong values. They are not actual values for RSRP and RSRQ.

The values I am getting are in the image below.
[image]

Can anyone help me out with this. Need proper values for RSRP and RSRQ.
The devices which I am using are all above 4.4.2.

Comment: Hi Juzer Dhuliawala, please can you help your question by telling us what values you are expecting to get?

Comment: Expected values are,
RSRP: -44 dBm to -140 dBm
RSRQ: -3 dB to -19.5 dB

Comment: Because this seems to be a string conversion problem rather than an LTE problem, please add some tags for the programming language.

Comment: Hi bro ..Can you give the code how to get those values?

Answer (score 1):

This a chipset limitation issue, some chipsets provide this info others wont. Here is what others have encountered in obtaining the data (http://www.gyokovsolutions.com/survey/surveyresults.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is a mapping table for both RSRP and RSRQ.

There seems to be an error in following :
1. Mapping between the measured value in dBm and reported RSRP 
2. Mapping the RSRQ value with the absolute power

The error could be in terms of fetching or using with the correct datatype.